# Cannot find module '@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack'

Tags: microservices, jhipster

I'm new to JHipster and using current version (8.1.0 latest till date) to create microservice app with JHipster registry and Angular microfrontend.
After creation, when I try to start it (with mvnw command on Windows cmd), the build fails stating:
**Cannot find module '@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack'** in few of the files as shown in the attached screenshot.
[Build failure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpUXE.png)

My JHipster Registry service is up and running fine (before starting microservice app).
Also, I'm using latest version of npm (9.8.1) and node (20.10.0).
Attaching the input parameters I've used while creating the app.
[Input parameters screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBeBQ.png)

Please help me understand where I went wrong (or) how to resolve it.

Comment: Can you please try with Node 18 and see if that solves the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MattRaible
As you suggested, I uninstalled my current Node version and installed Node v18.
The issue still persists.

Comment: Please clear my doubt:
For all my microservices, I'm using Hazelcast cache. For my gateway corresponding to these microservices, should I use Hazelcast or no cache?

Comment: I don't think WebFlux had caching support until the Spring 3.2 release. I could be wrong.

Comment: Hi @MattRaible
I used this command to resolve the issue: `jhipster jdl reactive-mf.jdl --monorepository --workspaces`
Don't know why, but including **--monorepository** in the command resolves the build failure.
If we don't include it, the gateway app works fine, but build fails for microservices apps.
As it's not always advisable to have common Git repo for all the apps in the project, please suggest any other way to resolve the issue.

Details:
JHipster - v8.1.0
Java - v17
Node - v18.19.0
NPM - v9.8.1

Comment: Can you please enter an issue into the JHipster project on GitHub with the steps to reproduce the problem? Linking back to this Q&A might be helpful too.

Comment: Hi @MattRaible. Thanks for your reply.
As suggested, I added an issue [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/24745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in v8.1.0 and should be fixed in next release.

##### About workspaces/monorepository options

Workspaces option uses npm scripts designed to match monolith applications so we can use common ci scripts.

The problem happens because there is no way to create npm scripts without making it a workspaces root.

Project structure with workspaces:
/package.json
/package-lock.json
/microservice-1/package.json
/microservice-2/package.json

Project structure without workspaces:
/microservice-1/package.json
/microservice-1/package-lock.json
/microservice-2/package.json
/microservice-2/package-lock.json

If you try to mix both structures it will have unknown results.

Workspaces should be used in monorepositories only.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix installing angular-architects/module-federation:

npm i @angular-architects/module-federation